# Docker Compose - Logstash - exited with code 0 after start

Tags: docker, logstash, docker-compose, logstash-configuration

I'm trying to use Logstash with Docker Compose, the .yml file looks like this:

```
user-service:
image: images/user-service
ports:
  - "2222:2222"
links:
 - logstash

logstash:
image: images/logstash
command: logstash -e 'input{} output{}'
ports:
  - "5045:5045"
```

And logstash starts and ends, as the console shows:

```
logstash_1          | Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
logstash_1          | 01:51:30.164 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO    logstash.pipeline - Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250}
logstash_1          | 01:51:30.246 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
logstash_1          | 01:51:30.860 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
logstash_1          | 01:51:33.318 [LogStash::Runner] WARN  logstash.agent - stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
docker_logstash_1 exited with code 0
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you sure about the indenting of your yml file?

Comment: I solved it changing the command, I used 
` input{ tcp{
            port=> 9600
            host=>localhost
        }
  }
output{ stdout{} } `

But I dont know how to do the logbak.xml file, 

`<appender name="stash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>logstash:5045</destination>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>`

How do I have to put in the destinarion tag logstash:5045 or logstash:5045?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it changing the input from the filter:

```
input{ tcp{
        port=> 9600
        host=>localhost
    }
}
```